# Window title in AutoHotKeys

Tags: autohotkey

In AutoHotKeys, how do I write an if/then statement that says:

```
::create::
IF(Window.Title == 'Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio') {
   SendInput CREATE TABLE dbo.xxx({Enter}
   SendInput xxxID Int Identity(101,1) CONSTRAINT xxxID Primary Key{Enter}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#IfWinActive Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio 
::create:: 
SendInput CREATE TABLE dbo.xxx({Enter} 
SendInput xxxID Int Identity(101,1) CONSTRAINT xxxID Primary Key{Enter} 
return
```

Answer (score 4):

There are many different ways of getting a window title but I would say the best option is to use The WinGetTitle command:

```
WinGetTitle, Window_Title, A ;A is for the active window
If (Window_Title = "Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio") {
}
```

Comment: I like this way. In my situation, I am already using #IfWinActive to test ahk_class to see if I am in Eclipse.. and now I want to test if I am working on a .java file.

Answer (score 2):

I think you would be best served by the [IfWinActive](http://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/IfWinActive.htm) command.  Below is an example that is triggered when you press Win+C

```
#c::
  IfWinActive, Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio
    Send, CREATE TABLE dbo.xxx({Enter}xxxID Int Identity(101,1) CONSTRAINT xxxID Primary Key{Enter}
return
```